# Java, Spring - Logging Bean Properties

Tags: java, spring, logging

Say I have the following bean definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
         <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
```

Is there a way to get Spring to log all of the properties that it has set (without enabling verbose logging for Spring in log4j). I was thinking of something along the lines of... verbose="true"

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" verbose="true">
```

---

**Update**

I used the following, as suggested in the answer:

```
public class SpringBeanLoggingPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpringBeanLoggingPostProcessor.class);
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean.getClass() == org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.class) {
            BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource) bean;
            log.info("url="+ds.getUrl());
            log.info("username="+ds.getUsername());
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String arg1) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such a facility. You can create a dedicated bean post processor that logs target bean properties for that.